# How to vertical and horizontal align a div inside another div?

Tags: html, css

How do I vertical and horizontal align a div inside another div?

Basically, I'm trying to align `<div id="middle2">` inside `<div id="middle">`.

```
<div id="middle">
    <div id="middle2">
        <span id="sp1"class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-w" style="float:left;"></span>
        <div class="middleContent"></div>
            <span id="sp2" class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-e" style="float:left;"></span>
        </div>
```

This is the CSS I've tried:

```
.middleContent
{
    background-color: white;
    height: 22px;
    width: 90%;
    border: 1px solid #252C3E;
    float: left;
}
#middle2
{
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Vertical align is not as straightforward as horizontal align. **[This page](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/)** explains a few different methods to achieve vertical align.

Comment: thanks rfausak pointing me to the article, the vertical aligning is now working but not the horizantal.

Comment: For horizontal align, use `text-align: center;` for your "middle" div, and `margin: auto` for your "middle2" div.

Comment: Horizontal is still not working after following your latest suggestions of setting margin: auto for div (middle2) and setting text-align: center for div (middle)

Answer (score 1):

http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html the article of all articles on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to horizontally align the `middle2` div inside the `middle` div? You haven't specified a width for either, so both divs will have the same width and horizontal align effectively won't do anything here.

I think what you want is to horizontally align the `middleContent` div inside the `middle2` div. Since `middleContent` is set at 90% width, the effect of the horizontal align should be noticeable. To do this, add the following to your CSS code:

```
#middle2 {
  text-align: center;
}

#middleContent {
  margin: auto;
}
```

That should do it. If it's still not working, please update your question with your latest code.